# Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have $a ≥ b − ε$. Show that $a \geq b $

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question that asks to prove the following:
Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have $a ≥ b − ε$. Show that $a \geq b $
I thought it would be good to try by contrapositive. Suppose that $b>a$. We want to prove that $b- \epsilon >a $ and this implies $b>a+ \epsilon$.. But this really leads nowhere and doesn't prove anything. I thought about a direct proof, but that didn't work out either. I set a in terms of b which gave me an equality so we could conclude that a is at least the same as b, but it didn't seem correct. Or it seems like it needed to be a proof by cases. I know this is a fairly straight forward, simple proof, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

If $a \ge b$ is false, then $a < b$; set

$\epsilon = \dfrac{b - a}{2} > 0; \tag 1$

then

$b - \epsilon = b - \dfrac{b - a}{2} = \dfrac{2b - b + a}{2} = \dfrac{a + b}{2} > a, \tag 2$

which contradicts

$a \ge  b - \epsilon; \tag 3$

thus, by *redudtio ad absurdum*, we must have

$a \ge b; \tag 4$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $a<b$ and consider $\epsilon=\frac{b-a}2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that $a, b$ are fixed real numbers where as $\epsilon$ is not fixed. The statement "$a\geq b-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$" is not just a single inequality, rather it represents infinitely many inequalities (one for each $\epsilon>0)$.

And now start your proof by contradiction and assume $b>a$. This should invalidate at least one of your infinitely many inequalities mentioned in last paragraph. You have to find one such inequality and that means finding the corresponding positive $\epsilon$.

This is not difficult. The given inequalities can be written as $\epsilon\geq b-a$ and to invalidate this one just needs to choose a positive $\epsilon<b-a$. Since by assumption we have $b-a>0$ we can find $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon<b-a$. A particular explicit value is $\epsilon =(b-a) /2$, but it is not necessary to write an explicit value of $\epsilon$ for the argument to work.

You can now write a short answer like this:

> Assume on the contrary that $b>a$ so that $b-a$ is positive. Let's now take any $\epsilon $ with $0<\epsilon<b-a$ and this means $a<b-\epsilon$ which contradicts one of the given inequalities. Hence we must have $a\geq b$.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to what others have suggested.

Since $b-\epsilon\leq a$ for every $\epsilon >0$.

Consider the following two sequences $x_n=a$, constant sequence and $y_n=b-\epsilon_n$, where $\epsilon_n=1/n$

Now using the fact that

> If $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\} $ are two sequences with limit $x,y$ respectively
>   and $x_n\leq y_n$ for all $n$, then $x\leq y$

Apply this, In our case $\lim x_{n}=a$ and $\lim y_n=b$ and $y_n\leq x_n$ for all $n$, so $b\leq a$

Comment: You don't really need limit machinery in order to prove basic inequalities of an ordered field. The properties of order relations are sufficient to prove the result

Comment: Yes. I know it is an overkill!!